# If, elif, else in Python does not follow my rules

Tags: python

So basically I have a simple IF/ELIF/ELIF/ELSE statement as such:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(df)):
    if df.col_one[i] == 'Three':
        print df.col_one[i]
        print df.col_text[i]
    elif df.col_one[i] == 'Two':
        print df.col_one[i]
        print df.col_text[i]
    elif df.col_one[i] == 'One':
        print df.col_one[i]
        print df.col_text[i]
    else:
        pass
```

The data is just a simple dataframe which I read in from Excel:

```
col_one  col_text
One      Text1
Two      Text2
Three    Text3
```

However, when I run the if/elif/elif/else command below, it prints out 'One', 'Text1' first then 'Two', 'Text2' and lastly 'Three', 'Text3'. But I tell Python to print exactly the opposite. How is this possible?

Comment: The order of your `if`/`elif` clauses doesn't matter here... you're looping over your data in `('One', 'Two', 'Three')` order.

Comment: how come each of your `if` statements do the same thing? you might as well not have it there at all

Comment: Here is my advice: take a pen and a paper, and do the iteration by yourself. For each value of i from 0 to 2, do your block, follow your own instructions, and you'll see that Python does precisely what you told it to do.

Comment: @mangoHero1 I imagine it's for testing. The contents of the `if`/`elif` blocks aren't really relevant to the question.

Comment: @glibdud point taken. just found it to be a little redundant. :P

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try some different things.

Comment: Can someone at least point me in the right direction instead of y'all telling me I´m wrong? I'm trying to learn..

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand what you are asking Python to do. The `if/elif/else` order is not saying that you will print it in that order. It is just a control structure to only print those items if they are one that you have. The `for` loop is the reason that it is printing it in the order you aren't expecting. If you want to print 3, 2, 1. Then you will need to either reverse the order of the arrays or reverse the order of the index of the for loop, to make it count backwards from 2.

Comment: It's not about reversing it. It's about printing it in the order I want as I have more than three variables. And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: But what do I need to use so that I can just choose the row I want based on a value without having to endlessly write new for and if statements?

Comment: If you want to choose the row and you know the number of rows won't change, you can just access the index of the arrays individually.